# IIS URL rewriting rule not working for entire site

Tags: asp.net, iis, redirect, rules

My target is to forward the following URL's to the new site (exact matches is needed since I have other rules with oldsite.com/test.aspx):

- oldsite.com
- oldsite.com/
- www.oldsite.com
- www.oldsite.com/
- **Only the ones from above (statically) i do not want to forward oldsite.com/test.aspx for example**

What I used is:

```
<rule name="Redirect" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="oldsite.com$" ignoreCase="false" />
                    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAny">
                        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="oldsite.com" />
                        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="www.oldsite.com" />
                        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="oldsite.com/" />
                        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="www.oldsite.com/" />
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Redirect" url="http://newsite.com" appendQueryString="false" />
                </rule>
```

My rule doesn't work and I was wondering why

Comment: Typical mistake in `match` tag https://blog.lextudio.com/the-very-common-mistakes-when-using-iis-url-rewrite-module-a2ab7e4fee59

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An HTTP Host header never contains a `/`,  so your `{HTTP_HOST}` conditions ending with `/` are redundant.

`<match url="oldsite.com$"` on the other hand simply means that match only with paths (not URLs) ending with `oldsite.com`.

e.g.:

- `http://whatever/something-oldsite.com` matches.
- `http://whatever/oldsite.com` matches.
- `http://whatever/oldsite.comA` not matches.
- `http://whatever/oldsite.co` not matches.

Apparently this is not what you want.

Besides, bear in mind that a literal dot character (`.`) means "match with any character" in Regular Expressions. This unexpectedly causes your pattern to match match with an URL like `http://whatever/oldsiteZcom` for example. Remember to escape dots with backslashes in the patterns when you are looking for literal dots.

The `url` attribute of `<match>` element is here a little bit ambiguous, I always wonder why Microsoft choose this name, something like `<match path="..` would be clearer but this is what we have with the URL Rewrite module. I understand your confusion, I was there.

Anyways, you're looking for exact empty paths so you need a rule like below.

```
<rule name="Redirect" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="^$" ignoreCase="false" /> <!-- path is empty, just starts (^) and ends ($), does not contain anything -->
    <conditions>
        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^oldsite\.com$" /> <!-- host name literally equals to oldsite.com -->
        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^www\.oldsite\.com$" /> <!-- host name literally equals to www.oldsite.com -->
    </conditions>
    <action type="Redirect" url="http://newsite.com" appendQueryString="false" />
</rule>
```

Hope it helps.